# Import multiple csv files using loops

Tags: python

I'm using google colab and I'm trying to import multiple csv files from google drive to the program.

I know how to import the datasets one by one but I'm not sure how to create a loop that reads in all of the csv files so that I can just have one line of code that imports all of the datasets for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary with all dataframes like this:

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

filepaths = glob('/content/drive/My Drive/location_of_the_files/*.csv')
dfs = {f'df{n}': pd.read_csv(i) for n, i in enumerate(filepaths)}
```

Individual dataframes can then be accessed with `dfs['df0']`, `dfs['df1']`, etc.

Comment: Note: `glob` might not work for reading from Google Drive unless the volume is mounted somehow in Colab

Comment: @OneCricketeer True, that is the assumption based on the little information in the question. Otherwise [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown) may come in useful.